# XCode Locks Up When Launching the iOS Simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

Lately when I have been deploying any iOS application to the simulator (iPad or iPhone), XCode locks up (Not Responding) and the simulator simply displays a black screen. I have to force quit both.

**Steps I have taken so far towards a resolution:**

1. Clean
2. Reset the Simulator
3. Deleted the simulator folder
4. Reinstalled XCode from the App Store
5. Reinstalled XCode from the developer center

Has anyone else encountered this? Any suggestions for a solution?

**Other info:**

- OSX Lion 10.7.3
- XCode 4.3.2
- Shibboleet

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Do you have a static library in your code?

Comment: Actually, it happens on all project (static lib or not).  It even happens after creating a brand new project.

Comment: My Xcode/simulator lockup issue is slightly different and I've seen this in the last few releases (currently 4.5.1/Lion 10.7.5.) I can launch in the simulator just fine, say 8-10 times. Next time Xcode will say it's running, but the simulator still shows the springboard and that's all she wrote. I can't stop the app or quit Xcode (because it can't stop it either.) All I can do is quit the simulator and kill Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and was able to continue by:

1) Edit the run scheme by clicking on the first part of the App name to the right of the "Stop" button to bring down the scheme list and click "Edit Scheme..."

2) Click on the Run item and change the debugger from LLDB to GDB.

3) Run

I think the problem was that I validated the settings and it offered to automatically change the debugger from GDB and LLDB and I clicked "OK" because the advisor message sounded very self-assured.

Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

Under Scheme, go to edit scheme, and change launch from  wait for App.app to launch to automatically under the Info tab.

EDIT: If you upgraded Xcode, make sure the old separate simulator is uninstalled.

Comment: No go: XCode stops crashing, but the sim never launches. When I launch it manually, the app isn't installed.

Comment: Is the deployment target the same as the Simulator verison? iOS 5.1 for example?

Comment: Yes, FYI this happens with vanilla (new) projects as well.

Answer (score 0):

hmmm, weird simulator, instruments issue i had once would work when i command-tabbed back and forth. try deleting derived data?

Comment: you should also try cleaning /var/folders

Comment: sorry:-( hope you figure it out